# Error in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, plugins, vaadin

I have Eclipse Juno and want to add the Vaadin plug-in.
It appears though the following error:
 [image]

What can I do?

Comment: What URL are you trying?

Comment: @Techidiot i have tried http://vaadin.com/eclipse/3.5, http://vaadin.com/eclipse/4.3 and http://vaadin.com/eclipse. the last one cannot be even found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **avoid** this kind of **network/proxy issues**, You can use this [offline](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/vaadin-plug-in-for-eclipse) vaadin archive.

Installation:

1.Download the **zip file** to a location of your choice

2.Install the add-on in Eclipse

3.Select Help -> Install New Software

4.Add the archive as an update site (Add… -> Archive… -> select the downloaded file)

5.Check the “Vaadin” checkbox (or all plugins) and click ok

6.Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice from [Official Site](http://vaadin.com/eclipse)